# Перенести ASP.NET Identity в Autofac в ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, autofac, asp.net-identity-3

У меня есть инициализация ASP.NET Identity в Startup и я хочу перенести её в Autofac модуль. Поиски в интернете не дали никаких результатов т.к. я не совсем понимаю, как применить решения из ASP.NET Framework в ASP.NET5.
Вот мой Startup:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        /*Некоторая логика
        .................*/
       
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        
        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }
```

Я хочу перенести **services.AddDefaultIdentity...** в Autofac модуль для того, чтобы сборщик мог всё зарегистировать вместо встроенного ServiceCollection.
Я пробовал такое решение:

```
public class IdentityModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<HttpContextAccessor>().As<IHttpContextAccessor>().SingleInstance();
        builder.Register(c => new UserStore<IdentityUser>(c.Resolve<ApplicationDbContext>())).AsImplementedInterfaces().SingleInstance();
        builder.Register(c => new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(c.Resolve<ApplicationDbContext>())).AsImplementedInterfaces().SingleInstance();
        builder.Register(c => new ClaimsPrincipal(c.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext?.User)).As<IPrincipal>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<UserManager<IdentityUser>>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<SignInManager<IdentityUser>>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
    }
}
```

Но, когда я собираюсь вызвать **User.IsInRole()** в одном из view выбрасывается ошибка, которую я не могу решить.

```
DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 
'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' 
can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IPasswordHasher`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser
] passwordHasher' of constructor 'Void 
.ctor(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser
], Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityOptions], 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IPasswordHasher`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser, 
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserValidator`1[Mic
rosoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]], 
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IPasswordValidator`1
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]], 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ILookupNormalizer, 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityErrorDescriber, System.IServiceProvider, 
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsof
t.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]])'.
```

А так же вот такая ошибка

```
DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser, 
Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].
```

**UPD:**
Спасибо @4per, начал ковырять этот метод, он состоит из следующего кода:

```
public static IdentityBuilder AddDefaultIdentity<TUser>(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IdentityOptions> configureOptions) where TUser : class
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            o.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            o.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        })
        .AddIdentityCookies(o => { });

        return services.AddIdentityCore<TUser>(o =>
        {
            o.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128;
            configureOptions?.Invoke(o);
        })
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    }
```

Метод services.AddIdentityCore получилось реализовать зарегистрировав в сборщике UserManager и все прилегающие к нему сервисы по типу:

```
builder.Register<UserStore<IdentityUser>>(c => c.Resolve<ApplicationDbContext>())
```

Сайт хотя бы начал запускаться без ошибок, но вот страницы регистрации и входа не открываются т.к. нужно переписать services.AddAuthentication, как я понял. Это сделать у меня не вышло т.к. в этом методе довольно много internal классов, а так же логика сложнее, чем в инициализации UserManager'а и я запутался.

Comment: Загляните в реализацию метода расширения AddDefaultIdentity. Скорее всего вам надо будет переписать эту реализацию под автофак. Остальные два метода я надеюсь, можно будет вызвать также как в вашем текущем Startup, через флюент интерфейс. Но это всё не точно, надо смотреть реализацию и возвращемые типы, чтобы сказать точнее. А с автофаком я, к сожалению, не знаком.